# My App is Crashing when I accept Location permission in Android

Tags: java, android, flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                           java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient' appears in /data/app/~~HoTjggNHdM1UIyerWixvHg==/com.roadrunner.freight.haulnow.uat-F_nQfTK-B2W5wucbp4Mxig==/base.apk)

com.transistorsoft.xms.g.location.SettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(Unknown Source:70)

com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.activity.TSLocationManagerActivity.checkLocationSettings(Unknown Source:29)com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.activity.TSLocationManagerActivity.execute(Unknown Source:47)com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.activity.TSLocationManagerActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:14)android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4009)

android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201)

android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)

android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)

android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)

android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)

android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

I am using Location plugin and geolocator plugin but still It crashes

Comment: Can you add some code please ? as per error it looks like you have made mistake for ```SettingsClient```  import statement

Comment: I have updated my android sdk to latest version and after that I am facing this issue, as soon as I allow location permission, app crashes and when I deny permission it works fine.

Comment: Provide the code and check if geolocator plugin has newer version

Comment: Can you provide the code of your gradle libraries dependencies?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.